# Where can I find a map of paid street parking zones in Munich?

Tags: automobiles, munich

Some parts of Munich have street parking which is either charged by the hour or only available to local residents. People traveling to Munich by car might be interested in finding out the parking regulations in advance so that they don't have to circle around looking for a suitable place to park.

Where can one find a detailed map of paid parking zones in Munich?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94690/where-can-i-find-a-map-of-paid-street-parking-zones-in-munich

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general map of the parking areas is available from the official [government website](https://muenchenunterwegs.de/parklizenzgebiete) of Munich:

[image: munich parking zones]

The red and blue areas have paid and residential parking, the yellow and brown ones plan to implement it in the future, and the rest is free of charge. After locating your area of interest, checkout the [following page](https://www.muenchen.de/rathaus/Stadtverwaltung/Kreisverwaltungsreferat/Verkehr/Parkraummanagement.html) to get a detailed map of each neighborhood, including the per-hour pricing:

[image]

Comment: Posting this as a community wiki to encourage locals to contribute, if necessary.